# Add mean and sd column in correlation matrix in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm trying to create correlation matrix that also includes means and sd's of each variable.

```
** Set variables used in Summary and Correlation
 local variables relationship commission anxiety enjoyment negotiation_efficacy similarity_values similarity_behaviors SPT_confidence own_SPT_effort 


** Descriptive statistics
estpost summarize `variables'
matrix table = ( e(mean) \ e(sd) )
matrix rownames table = mean sd
matrix list table

** Correlation matrix
correlate `variables'
matrix C = r(C)
local k = colsof(C)
matrix C = C[1..`=`k'-1',.]
local corr : rownames C
matrix table = ( table \ C )
matrix list table

estadd matrix table = table

local cells table[count](fmt(0) label(Count)) table[mean](fmt(2) label(Mean)) table[sd](fmt(2) label(Standard Deviation))
local drop
foreach row of local corr {
    local drop `drop' `row'
    local cells `cells' table[`row'](fmt(4) drop(`drop'))
}
display "`cells'"

esttab using Report.rtf, 
        replace
        noobs 
        nonumbers 
        compress
        cells("`cells'")
```

If it helps, this is what the correlation code looks like:

```
asdoc corr relationship commission anxiety enjoyment negotiation_efficacy similarity_values similarity_behaviors SPT_confidence own_SPT_effort ranger_SPT_effort cooperative_motivation competitive_motivation, nonum
```

This correlation matrix looks exactly how it should, but I'm essentially hoping to add means and sd's to the beginning.

*This is cross-posted here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1549809-add-mean-and-sd-column-in-correlation-matrix-in-stata

Comment: Given your interest in `asdoc` (from SSC, as you are asked to explain) I would post this on Statalist. There is one expert on `asdoc`, its author, and he doesn't hang out here.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I'll go ahead and post it over there, thanks for all your help! Still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear for me whether you want the table to include significance stars or not. If not you can just use corr and a loop to obtain sd and mean, then use frmttable. Seems shorter than your current example. Here's an example

```
bcuse wage2


global variables "wage hours educ exper"

corr $variables 

matrix corr_t = r(C)

local rows = rowsof(corr_t)
di "`rows'"

matrix add = J(`rows',2,.)

matrix list add

local n = 1
foreach x of global variables {
    sum `x'
    mat add[`n',1] = r(sd)
    mat add[`n',2] = r(mean)
    local n = `n' + 1
}


matrix final = corr_t,add
matrix list final


frmttable, statmat(final) sdec(2) ctitle("","wage", "hours", "educ", "exper","sd","mean") rtitle("wage"\ "hours"\ "educ" \ "exper")
```